# TFS2012 Adapting Bug Item WIT

Tags: tfs

While I was following the guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj920163.aspx to add Bugs to the task board I ran into an unexpected issue.

Adding the fields to the WIT was successful but when I started adding the form fields I received a very strange error:

> Failed to save the 'Bug' Work Item Type to the server. Please contact
>   your administrator. There was an error contacting the server.
>   Technical information (for administrator): HTTP code 200: OK

Now I played around trying to find what field was causing the error... I tried every field seperatly and when added seperately they worked, then I tried adding them in pairs, this worked as well, then I tried adding all of them and even this worked!
BUT: When I try to add all of them in a clean group and column I get the error!

This leads me to believe there is some sort of maximum amount of elements in the layout form of a WIT? For now we have left all the fields added to another category but I wanted to ask if someone else had run into this issue and if there is a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today we figured out what was going on by using fiddler and more closely monitoring the exchange between Visual Studio and our TFS server. Apparently the request was hitting the Application Firewall that was installed on the TFS server. This is the reason why you receive the vague error `HTTP code 200: OK`. The Application Firewall replies with a plain HTML page containing a blocked request ID (so you can pass it to your system admin). Once we passed this ID on to our networking team and they adapted the rules there was no longer an issue.

I hope this helps anyone who unexpectedly runs into an Application Firewall on your TFS server like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are all stored as columns in a SQL Server table, the maximum you can add is 1024 (less the TFS standard, which might be around 33 columns?)

If you think this is the problem, check the Tfs_Warehouse..DimWorkItem table and see if you exceed the maximum.

Any chance you can get more information from the event viewer log on the app server, or provide more information about your bug? That message isn't very useful.

For reference -

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugenez/archive/2009/05/07/work-item-customization-tidbits-limits-of-complexity-part-13-of-x.aspx